# tshark SIP protocol display collapse

Tags: linux, sip, tshark

I'm using tshark protocol filter as I need to parse the contents of the SIP Packets.

```
tshark -r df32c2248fe646a6793ce9a63b124b34@0.0.0.0.pcap -O sip
```

I get this:

```
Frame 14: 553 bytes on wire (4424 bits), 553 bytes captured (4424 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 4.4.4.4 (4.4.4.4), Dst: 3.3.3.3 (3.3.3.3)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 5060 (5060), Dst Port: 5060 (5060)
Session Initiation Protocol (200)
    Status-Line: SIP/2.0 200 OK
        Status-Code: 200
        [Resent Packet: False]
        [Request Frame: 11]
        [Response Time (ms): 115]
        [Release Time (ms): 115]
    Message Header
        Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 2.2.2.2:5060;received=3.3.3.3;branch=z9hG4bK18f6609d-1c76-4a8b-a96b-2cf7d8036d36_6772d868_3067109296759172
            Transport: UDP
            Sent-by Address: 2.2.2.2
            Sent-by port: 5060
            Received: 3.3.3.3
            Branch: z9hG4bK18f6609d-1c76-4a8b-a96b-2cf7d8036d36_6772d868_3067109296759172
        Contact: <sip:14082186500@1.1.1.1:17060>
            Contact URI: sip:14082186500@1.1.1.1:17060
                Contact URI User Part: 14082186500
                Contact URI Host Part: 1.1.1.1
                Contact URI Host Port: 17060
        To: <sip:14082186500@spicyramen.ippbx.com;user=phone>;tag=83174026
            SIP to address: sip:14082186500@spicyramen.ippbx.com;user=phone
                SIP to address User Part: 14082186500
                SIP to address Host Part: spicyramen.ippbx.com
                SIP To URI parameter: user=phone
            SIP to tag: 83174026
        From: <sip:anonymous@sip.ie1.sipprovider.com>;tag=87638703_6772d868_18f6609d-1c76-4a8b-a96b-2cf7d8036d36
            SIP from address: sip:anonymous@sip.ie1.sipprovider.com
                SIP from address User Part: anonymous
                SIP from address Host Part: sip.ie1.sipprovider.com
            SIP from tag: 87638703_6772d868_18f6609d-1c76-4a8b-a96b-2cf7d8036d36
        Call-ID: df32c2248fe646a6793ce9a63b124b34@0.0.0.0
        CSeq: 44365 BYE
            Sequence Number: 44365
            Method: BYE
        User-Agent: 3CXPhoneSystem 14.0.44198.522 (44097)
        Content-Length: 0
```

As you can see output is not collapse. I want to see something like this:

```
Frame 14: 553 bytes on wire (4424 bits), 553 bytes captured (4424 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 4.4.4.4 (4.4.4.4), Dst: 3.3.3.3 (3.3.3.3)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 5060 (5060), Dst Port: 5060 (5060)
Session Initiation Protocol (200)
    Status-Line: SIP/2.0 200 OK
    Message Header
        Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 2.2.2.2:5060;received=3.3.3.3;branch=z9hG4bK18f6609d-1c76-4a8b-a96b-2cf7d8036d36_6772d868_3067109296759172
        Contact: <sip:14082186500@1.1.1.1:17060>
        To: <sip:14082186500@spicyramen.ippbx.com;user=phone>;tag=83174026
        From: <sip:anonymous@sip.ie1.sipprovider.com>;tag=87638703_6772d868_18f6609d-1c76-4a8b-a96b-2cf7d8036d36
        Call-ID: df32c2248fe646a6793ce9a63b124b34@0.0.0.0
        CSeq: 44365 BYE
        User-Agent: 3CXPhoneSystem 14.0.44198.522 (44097)
        Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wireshark
You can use Wireshark to do the job.
Apply a [display filter](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters):
sip

Go to the the [Packet Details](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUsePacketDetailsPaneSection.html) pane.
Expand "Session Initiation Protocol"
Expand Request-Line, Message Header and Message Body* (do not Expand Subtrees)
Go to File - Export - Export Packet Dissections... - As "Plain Text" File...
Packet Format section: select "Packet Summery Line" and "Packet Details: As Displayed"
Add a file name and save the file

*Note
I have used [sample file](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures#SIP_and_RTP): aaa.pcap
Message Body: see packet 223

[TShark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html)
You can use -T Fields and add all the [fields](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/s/sip.html) you need.
For example: 
tshark -r aaa.pcap -Y sip -E header=y -E separator="?" -T fields -e frame.number -e sip.Request-Line -e sip.r-uri  -e sip.Via -e sip.From -e sip.To -e sip.Call-ID -e sip.Contact -e sip.Expires -e sip.CSeq -e sip.User-Agent -e sip.Content-Length  > aaa.csv

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking an option in tshark since I need to do this programatically.

Comment: Perhaps TShark -T Fields can help. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I used, tcpdump -qns 0 -A -r filename.pcap > filename.txt and then remove the 28 bytes in the SIP URI line.  E..D....@..... ..........0..INVITE sip:+14081112222@1.1.1.1 SIP/2.0

Comment: joke, thanks very much - worked great!  I reposted the Wireshark portion with attribution at [the Wireshark Q&A site](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/19411/how-to-get-only-the-headers-of-a-packet/50433).